# Overlapping widgets in shiny

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny

In shiny, I would like the user to be able to write a third  value for "sex" in the text box if she so whishes even though only 'male' and 'female' are included in the "choices" vector.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("foo", label = "sex", choices = c("male","female"), selectize = T)
)

server <- function(input, output) {      
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I can do this with an additional text field and an 'add new option' button (as has been suggested in other so questions). However, I would like the user to be able to type the new option right in the original text box.

Comment: Have an 'other' choice and then display a text input box in the same position.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea. I wanted to write the new category right into the text box, but I guess it just doesn't work like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed this following 42's suggestion:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fixedRow(
    column(4,
           conditionalPanel(
             condition = "input.sex != 'other'",
             selectInput("sex", label = "sex", choices = c("male","female","other"), selectize = T)
           )
    )
  ),
  fixedRow(
    column(4,
           conditionalPanel(
             condition = "input.sex == 'other'",
             textInput("sex_o", "write sex")
           )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```